# TypeError when trying to edit a TODO APP list

Tags: python

Getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

I am Trying to Edit the list in TODO APP , which contain add , show , edit complete or exit .
My code:

```
todos = []

while True:
    user_action = input("Type Add, Show, Edit, Complete or exit: ")
    user_action = user_action.strip()
    match user_action:
        case 'add':
            todo = input("Enter a To-D0: ")
            todO = todo.capitalize()
            todos.append(todO)
        case 'show':
            for index, item in enumerate(todos):
                row = f"{index + 1 }:-{item}"
                print(row)

        case 'edit':
            number = (input("Number of To-Do to Edit:"))
            number = number - 1
            new_todo = input("Enter new To_Do: ")
            todos[number] = new_todo
        case 'complete':
            number = int(input("Value you want to Complete:"))
            todos.pop(number - 1)
        case 'exit':
            break 
print("Bye")
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string.  You need to convert to an integer.  `number = int(input("..."))`

Comment: And you're already doing that for the "complete" case.  Why aren't you also doing it for the "edit" case?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap the `input()` function with the `int()` function. Modified code:

```
todos = []

while True:
    user_action = input("Type Add, Show, Edit, Complete or exit: ")
    user_action = user_action.strip()
    match user_action:
        case 'add':
            todo = input("Enter a To-D0: ")
            todO = todo.capitalize()
            todos.append(todO)
        case 'show':
            for index, item in enumerate(todos):
                row = f"{index + 1 }:-{item}"
                print(row)

        case 'edit':
            number = int(input("Number of To-Do to Edit:")) #Wrap the input function with int function
            number = number - 1
            new_todo = input("Enter new To_Do: ")
            todos[number] = new_todo
        case 'complete':
            number = int(input("Value you want to Complete:"))
            todos.pop(number - 1)
        case 'exit':
            break 
print("Bye")
```